# Thunderbird calendar location

Tags: location

All my calendars' properties show `moz-storage-calendar://` as the location except my most important which shows `googleapi://agnarjohanson/?calendar=agnarjohanson%40gmail.com`. So it must be stored on Google. I want to change this so it is the same as the others, is stored on my computer and then I can break the connection to Google by (I guess) uninstalling `provider`. I no longer want to sync the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest way would be to:

1. open your Google calendar in a web browser
2. go to settings/calendars and export calendars (this will download a zip file)
3. extract the zip file
4. in Thunderbird, create a new calendar
5. import the contents of the zip file into the new calendar
6. delete the Google calendar from Thunderbird.

Comment: If you think this is the correct answer, please "accept" it by clicking the tick mark next to it. Thank you!